# I need to create a class within a class that uses previous class parameters as name and parameters itself

Tags: java

I've read a fair bit about the Class.forName("name") constructor but I'm not entirely sure how to implement it into my problem.

I have a class in another save file called "Plan" and this one called "Account" but i need to set Account's parameters namely String plan_name and int bal to the Plan class.

```
  public class Account
  {
  public Account(String plan_name, int bal)
  {
  Plan plan_name = new Plan(bal);
  }
  }
```

Comment: `Plan plan = new Plan(plan_name, bal);`

Comment: all you need to do is to overide the plan class constructor to accept 2 parameters ex:- `public Plan(String plan_name, int bal)` and create the instance of plan using  `Plan plan_name = new Plan(plan_name,bal);`

Answer (score 0):

Create a constructor in your Plan class

```
public Plan(String name,int bal){
   //your code do something

}
```

and then use this constructor in the Account class constructer like this

```
Plan plan_name = new Plan(plan_name,bal)
```